# Why is my ejs file not being rendered after I put my static files in public folder and added the code app.use(express.static("public"));

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

Everything worked fine and the list.ejs is being rendered correctly, until I moved the index.html and css files in the public folder and added the app.use(express.static("public)) is in app.js.

```
const express = require("express");

const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  
const today = new Date();
  
const options = {
    
week: 'long',
    
year:'numeric',
    
month:'long',
    
day:'numeric'
  
}
  
let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  
res.render("list.ejs",{kindOfDay:day} );

});


app.listen(3000, function(){

  console.log("Server is up and running on Port 3000.");

});
```

my file structure:

main folder
|
|___***public
|           |*** index.html
|
|__****views
|**** list.ejs

Comment: My current file structure as seen in atom:
myToDoList folder

|_node_modules folder
|_public folder   
|  |__css folder
|       |          |__styles.css
|       |
|       |___index.html
|
|_views folder
|     |___list.ejs
|
|_app.js
|
|_package.lock.json
|_package.json

Please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  We have pretty strict rules in place for questions, one of which is to put all relevant information inside the question prompt.  Also, please make use of the code formatting options in order to create a readable code example.  Both markdown and code snippets are supported for formatting.  Please edit your question to include both these requirements.

Comment: @PsiKai  the OP need not add further details beyond the express code producing the error. I agree  the OP could make use of information on the help center about [how to format posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in regards colde blocks and/syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

**Express.static completes requests it has reponded to.**

`app.use(express.static("public"));` completes the request by sending files requested using GET if they were found in the public folder. Hence if a file were found and returned, the static server never calls its `next` function argument. Note `express.static()` will look for `index.html` by default if no file name is provided in the URL.

In other words, if the file was served by `express.static()', the next line in the App,

```js
   app.get("/", function(req, res){
```

is never called and the

```js
 `   res.render("list.ejs",{kindOfDay:day}
```

statement never executed.

The solution is to

- Not put `.ejs` files in the public directory - they are not meant to be served directly.
- Generally restrict ejs processing to files that were requested with a `.ejs` extension.
- If always wanting to serve a home page (requested without filepath) by rendering it, place home page serving code:

```js
   app.get("/", function(req, res){ /* ... handle request */ };
```

before code setting up the static server. The reason it to guard against the case of an "index.html" file being present in the root of the public folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I get it. I'm quite new to this so I'm trying my best to understand. 

Just one question, index.html  is in my "public" folder, but list.ejs file is in "views" folder. 

my file structure:

main folder
|
|______public
|                   |___ index.html
|
|______views 
                  |____ list.ejs


Does it mean that even tho list.ejs is in views folder & not public , index.html is still be served first because app.use(express.static("public")); is set up first before my app.get("/". function(req, res){ res.render("list.ejs", {kindOfDay:day})}); ?

Comment: In a word yes. You can provide an [options](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.static) object when setting up `express.static` - have a look at the 'index` option in the link. By default the static server looks for "index.html" to serve as an index. But you can configure it to look for another filename, or as I just read, set it to `false` to not look for an index file at all. So now you also have the option to set `index` to `false` in options to get the `appl.get("/" )` middle ware to execute where it is placed in posted code.

Comment: thank you so much! for now, the problem resolved when I created an html folder in the public folder and placed the index.html in the html folder. I'll take a look at this and update here as soon as I can. Thank youuu sooo mucchhhhhh!!!!!!!!